# WordPress unable to connect to MySQL from GCP Compute Engine VM

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, wordpress, google-compute-engine

I have a Google Cloud Platform Compute Engine VM instance where I have Apache installed. I wanted to put WordPress on here and have the MySQL database created locally instead of using another GCP Resource API.

I've finished installing MySQL locally and created a database and user and granted access as well. But when I try installing WordPress I get this error:

> **Error establishing a database connection**
>
> This either means that the username and password information in your
> `wp-config.php` file is incorrect or we can’t contact the database
> server at `localhost`. This could mean your host’s database server is
> down.

I've read that I might need to add the `mysql-server` tag to my VM instance and add a firewall rule to allow TCP 3306 which I have now set up. But when I retry WordPress it still gives the same error. I also tried using my static external IP address when trying to connect WordPress to the database but no dice. I don't know how else to troubleshoot this.

Also, if it helps, I installed MySQL 8.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL 8.x is actually ‘IS’ supported, but requires a slightly different command when creating the user and password, as version 8 expects passwords to be SHA256 encoded.

When creating the database user, with the MySQL prompt, use the following:

```
ALTER USER 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
```

So WITH mysql_native_password being the main difference.

To troubleshoot the case you can also check out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53979429/wordpress-error-establishing-a-mysql-database-connection-iis10)

Answer (score 0):

Have you setup the mysql instance? On RHEL, try a `mysql_secure_install` to configure it, `systemctl start mysql` and `systemctl enable mysql`

Is your database running?

`systemctl status mysql`
`ss -ln`
`netstat -lapton | grep 3306`

Comment: `systemctl status mysqld` shows that it's active and running.

Comment: what does `netstat -platon`  show?